# count instances of value included in result set with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

Apologies if the question title is not descriptive / well worded.

I want to be able to count how many instances of a certain value occur in rows that meet a certain criteria. Consider the following two tables, `queues` and `queue_contents`

**queues Table:**

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | queue A |
|  2 | queue B |
|  3 | queue C |
+----+---------+
```

**queue_contents table:**

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| id  | queue_id | foo_id |
+-----+----------+--------+
|  1  |        1 |    10  |
|  2  |        1 |    11  |
|  3  |        1 |    12  |
|  5  |        2 |    20  |
|  6  |        2 |    21  |
|  7  |        2 |    23  |
|  8  |        2 |    24  |
|  9  |        3 |    10  |
|  10 |        3 |    11  |
|  11 |        3 |    20  |
|  12 |        3 |    30  |
+-----+----------+--------+
```

I would like a query that outputs the following result when I query for `queue_id == 3`

```
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| queue_id | queue_name | total_count | contained_in_this_one |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
|        1 | queue A    |           3 |                     2 |
|        2 | queue B    |           4 |                     1 |
+----------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

I cannot figure out how to count instances of `foo_id` that occur in `queue_contents.foo_id WHERE queue_contents.queue_id == 3`

It is trivial enough to get the `total_count` for each queue, but when it comes to setting up the subquery and criteria, I am stumped. I feel that the solution involves using a subquery and counting the number of `foo_id`s that occur in that subquery, but I can't get it to work. I won't include the maaaany iterations of the following query I have tried, although this will give you an idea of the track I am on:

## `foo_id`s in this query

```
sq = db_session.query(Foo.id.label('foo_id')) \
               .join(QueueContent, QueueContent.foo_id == Foo.id) \
               .filter(QueueContent.queue_id == 3) \
               .subquery('sq')

foo_alias = aliased(Foo)

q2 = db_session.query(func.count(Foo.id).label('total_in_task'),
                      func.count(foo_alias.id).label('count_in_this_task'),
                      Queue.id.label('queue_id'),
                      Queue.name.label('queue_name')) \
             .join(foo_alias, foo_alias.id == Foo.id) \
             .join(QueueContent, QueueContent.foo_id == Foo.id) \
             .join(Queue, Queue.id == QueueContent.queue_id) \
             .filter(Queue.id != 3) \
             .group_by('queue_name', 'queue_id')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `queue_id` groups do not contain `foo_id` duplicates, you could use a LEFT JOIN:

```
qc2 = aliased(QueueContent)

session.query(QueueContent.queue_id,
              func.count(),
              func.count(qc2.foo_id)).\
    outerjoin(qc2, and_(qc2.queue_id == 3,
                        qc2.foo_id == QueueContent.foo_id)).\
    filter(QueueContent.queue_id != 3).\
    group_by(QueueContent.queue_id)
```

If they do, you could use an EXISTS subquery expression wrapped in NULLIF (or cast as integer and summed):

```
qc2 = aliased(QueueContent)

sq = session.query(qc2).\
    filter_by(queue_id=3, foo_id=QueueContent.foo_id).\
    exists()

session.query(QueueContent.queue_id,
              func.count(),
              func.count(func.nullif(sq, False))).\
    filter(QueueContent.queue_id != 3).\
    group_by(QueueContent.queue_id)
```

Both variants use the fact that COUNT(*expression*) produces the number of rows where value of *expression* is not NULL.